# Determining sum of series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am supposed to solve the following problem:

Find sum of the series and range of convergence of: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n!}x^{2n}$

I know that I have to use Taylor polynomial for $e^x$ because of factorial. But I do not have idea, how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Think what happens if you integrate this series term by term? :)

Comment: @alexander.cliffe, if I integrate it term by term I got: 0,6x,$10x^3$,$7x^5$, is it leading somewhere?

Comment: I reckon it should be something like $x^{2n+1}/n!$

Answer (score 2):

Integrating term by term (radius of convergence is infinity so this is fine) we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} x^{2n+1} =  x \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (x^2)^n = xe^{x^2}\,.
$$
Now we differentiate to work out the original function, giving
$$
(1+ 2x^2)e^{x^2}\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n!}x^{2n} &=& 2\sum_{\color{red}{n=1}}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(n-1)!} +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}. \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use 
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{x^2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}.
\end{eqnarray*}

> $e^{x^2}+2 x^2 (e^{x^2}-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: split it in two:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n+1}{n!}x^{2n}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2n\,\frac{ x^{2n}}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigl(x^2\bigr)^n}{n!}=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2n\,x^{2 n-1}}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigl(x^2\bigr)^n}{n!} \\
&=x\biggl(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}\biggr)^{\!\prime}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigl(x^2\bigr)^n}{n!}.
\end{align}